# Backprop absolute value of matrix

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm learning neural networks and can't wrap my head around how to do backprop on a model proposed by my professor. Say a weight matrix $A$ in some layer of the model is used to compute intermediate outputs:
$$
  y = |A|x,
$$
where $|A|$ means taking the element-wise absolute values of $A$.

How would I do backprop through this layer?

Comment: Hint: what's the derivative of the absolute value function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $y$ element-wise, we have $$y_i=\sum_{j} |a_{ij}| x_j$$

And, the derivative wrt $a_{ij}$
$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial a_{ij}}=\operatorname{sign}(a_{ij})x_j$$

because the derivative of the absolute value function is the sign function, assuming $a_{ij}\neq 0$. The derivative is actually not defined at $0$, but practically, this is not important. Also $\partial{y_k}/\partial a_{ij}=0$ for $k\neq i$. You can write this element-wise derivatives using either [numerator or denominator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#/Layout_conventions).